# Sad story - git+ssh+ruby

Tags: ruby, git, ssh

## Problem:

i need to verify git repo properties (ssh key,repo url) in ruby
solutions:

1) write ssh key into `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file and execute `git clone` command with repo url property - easiest way

- cause race conditions when multiple users trying to check theirs repos.

2) write key into any file and link server and key in `ssh.config` file than execute git in ordinal way

-`ssh.config` file has limited lenght(255 records)

3) add key via `ssh-agent` and execute git in ordinal way

- ruby can't handle passphrase request (if ssh key protected with passphrase)

## Resume:

so i need universal solution (like `ssh -i`) that is easy to use,clean,will work in multithread environment and all errors can be handled via basic IO (exec and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to make git use your own SSH wrapper.  That script could look at additional environment variables and invoke `ssh` with the appropriate options.